# .NET Core best linux server distribution

Tags: linux, .net-core, server, network-traffic

Can you recommend best choice for linux server distribution for my .NET Core application?

My Second question is about managing big traffic on this server.
Can you advice the way to manage request on the server and how to detect server overload and redirect request to server no two?
The idea is to have N count of server instances and have something before this to managing and transmit request according on server overload.

Iam looking for Open source solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linux distributions listed here on [.NET Core road map page](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md). I would use the one I'm most familiar with.

For web applications, you can use [Ngnix](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) as a reverse proxy (in combination with Kestrel web server) and load balancer. It is in fact recommended to use Kestrel with a reverse-proxy such as Ngnix. See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction) how to set up ASP.NET on Linux.

> Kestrel is great for serving dynamic content from ASP.NET, however the
>   web serving parts aren’t as feature rich as full-featured servers like
>   IIS, Apache or Nginx. A reverse proxy-server can allow you to offload
>   work like serving static content, caching requests, compressing
>   requests, and SSL termination from the HTTP server.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I forget to say that Iam looking for open source version.
OPEN SOURCE NGINX is not supporting load balancing.

Comment: @DanielRusnok You may try Apache instead https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html